# GQL query by key in Google App Engine Admin Console

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

Here is an example of a record I am trying to write a GQL Admin Console query for (not Python).

Decoded entity key:

```
packageName: name=com.mycompany.example > userId: name=someone@gmail.com
Entity key: ag...Qw
```

I've already tried:

```
SELECT * FROM userId where __key__ = KEY('userId', 'someone@gmail.com')
```

This does not find the record. I suspect this is due to the `userId` being a child under `packageName`... How do I write a GQL query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM userId WHERE __key__ = KEY('packageName', 'com.mycompany.example', 'userId','someone@gmail.com')
> ```

```
>     // SELECT * FROM ChildClassName WHERE __key__ = KEY('ParentClassName', 'ParentName, 'ChildClassName', 'ChildName'))
```

See the info about the [Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass?hl=es-419) class for more details.

hope this helps.