# How to retrieve data from gae datastore with a query applying condition

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Here is my problem. SInce I am using JDO, the data is saved in the datastore backend. Now I want to retrieve data with a query with a condition. For example,

```
public List<Query> getQueries(final EntityKind entityKind) throws RuntimeException  {
    System.out.println("In getQueries()!!!" + entityKind);
    if (entityKind == null) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "QueryService : getQueries() : entityKind is null.");
        throw new RuntimeException("QueryService : getQueries() : entityKind is null.");

    }
    final long entityId = entityKind.getId();
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();

    List<Query> queryList = (List<Query>) new TransactionTemplate(pm).execute(new TransactionCallback<List<Query>>() {
        public List<Query> doInTransaction(PersistenceManager pm) {

            javax.jdo.Query query = pm.newQuery(Query.class,"SELECT FROM Query WHERE entityKindId == entityId");    
            Collection<Query> c = pm.detachCopyAll((Collection<Query>) query.execute(entityId));
            return new ArrayList<Query>(c);
        }
    });

    return queryList;
}
```

But this is not working. I have also tried this,

```
public List<Query> getQueries(final EntityKind entityKind) throws RuntimeException  {
System.out.println("In getQueries()!!!" + entityKind);
if (entityKind == null) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "QueryService : getQueries() : entityKind is null.");
    throw new RuntimeException("QueryService : getQueries() : entityKind is null.");

}
final long entityId = entityKind.getId();
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();

List<Query> entityKindFields = (List<Query>) new TransactionTemplate(pm).execute(new TransactionCallback<List<Query>>() {
        public List<Query> doInTransaction(PersistenceManager pm) {
            javax.jdo.Query query = pm.newQuery(Query.class);
            query.setFilter("entityKindId == :entityId");
            Collection<Query> c = pm.detachCopyAll((Collection<Query>) query.execute(entityKindId));
            return new ArrayList<Query>(c);
        }
    });
return queryList;
}
```

This is also not working. Please help!

Comment: "This is not working" - and what happens? What is "Query" persistable type? I'd suggest that you debug your problem using the log; so set it to DEBUG level and concentrate on one bit of code. The first query is wrong - seemingly trying to use explicit parameters yet not declaring them. Basic JDO docs and the JDO spec define these things http://datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/jdoql.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve an entity by ID use the

```
pm.getObjectById(CLASS.class, ENTITY_ID);
```

If you want to retrieve it using GQL try [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117074/gql-query-by-key-in-google-app-engine-admin-console/15122142#15122142)